# Node js express project how to add environment variables

Tags: node.js, express

I am a java script full stack developer.
In the vue js I create two files in the root.

1. env.development
2. env.production

In my `main.js` file, I can access environment variables like this

```
process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE_X
```

How production and development differs in the vue js is,
if I use **npm run serve** project loaded the development environment variables. If I use **npm run build** it takes production environment variables. That's all in vue.

But in my `expressjs` project,

```
"start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node -e js",
```

This command will always responsible for the run project. I couldn't find two commands like in vue. I go though the tutorials every body says use the package called **dotenv**.

I couldn't figure out that how could this package identify the environments this is production and this is development.

End of the day I want to set my db password to 123456 in my local machine and root@123456 in the server. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue.js handles modes automatically, depending on the command (e.g. `serve` sets `NODE_ENV=development`, while `build` sets `NODE_ENV=production`).
Depending on the mode, it also automatically loads files with variables from disk.

### Environment variables in Node.JS

However, Node.JS does not do that by default, and you have to set up your application to handle environment variables.

In Node.JS you can pass variables via the shell command, for example:
`MY_VARIABLE=x node myapp.js` (by prepending the command with variables), and that will give you `process.env.MY_VARIABLE` inside your `myapp.js` application.
Following this behavior, there's a consensus on using `NODE_ENV` variable for setting up the environment mode.
For production use, you'd start your application using `NODE_ENV=production node myapp.js`, while for development `NODE_ENV=development node myapp.js`.
Of course, if your machine already has these environment variables set up (for instance in `.bash_profile`) you do not need to prepend your command with them.

As a practice, in development machines, you'd have these variables already set up on your machine, while production machines (e.g. docker containers, etc) start clean and you pass the environment variables when starting your application.
For example, Heroku (and other deployment services) allow you to set up environment variables which are set at machine start.

There's also the method of storing variables in files (such as the .env, or other files), but those you'd have to read from disk when your application starts.
And this is where `dotenv` (and `config` package) come in play.
What `dotenv` does, is it reads `.env` file stored in your application execution path (root of the app), and sets any variables defined there into `process.env` for Node.JS to use.
This is extremely useful for development machines, but on production it's recommended to not have files that store sensitive information in variables, but rather use system environment variables.
There is also the option, for production machines, to construct or load into the machine an `.env` file at machine setup time, into the app directory.

*Note:*

- never commit `.env` or config files that store passwords and sensitive information, to your repository
- never store *development* and *production* variables in the same file

### The dotenv approach

The best way to go about it, would be to use `dotenv`, and have different `.env` files, one on your development machine, and a different one on your production machine. That way, when your application starts, it reads the variables that are stored in the adjacent `.env`. This is the most secure and reliable way, in absence of means to pass environment variables to your production machine from a machine management application/interface.

The easiest way to set up your app with `dotenv` would be to set your `start` command to something like:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec \"node -r dotenv/config\" server.js"
```

and then in the `.env` file stored on your local/development machine you'd have something similar to:

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD=1235
DATABASE_USERNAME=joe-dev
...
```

and in the `.env` file on your production machine (server):

```
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root@1235
DATABASE_USERNAME=root
...
```

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding 
you don't have created and setup a config file and required it in your app.js or any other file.  let see for example  create config file

```
 const config = {
        "development":{
            "host":"localhost",
            "dbport":"27017",
            "port":"",
            "username":"",
            "password":"",
            "userdb":"",
            "passworddb":"123456",
            "authSource":"",   
            "database":"devDB"
},
        "staging":{
            "host":"",
            "dbport":"",
            "port":"",
            "username":"",
            "password":"",
            "passworddb":"@123456",
            "database":"stageDB",
        }, 
        "production":{
            "host":"",
            "dbport":"",
            "port":"",
            "userdb":"",
            "passworddb":"@123456",
            "username":"",
            "password":"",
            "database":"prodDB",
        }

    };
    module.exports = config;
```

then you have you setup a variable in your .env file like `NodeENV = 'prod'`
then import it into your files like

```
var config = require('./config')["process.env.NodeENV"];
```

and one more last thing dotenv is only used to loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env.

Comment: How does node js know this is production, this is staging, this is development?

Comment: create a file name .env and then set  declared variable for example  NodeENV = 'prod' ... here when you want to run your code as dev then change this value to dev like NodeENV = 'dev' same as stage . Remember you can set a name of variable you want

Comment: This is a bad practice for supplying configs that store sensitive information, to your application. Never store different environments in the same file. Also, the example has lost of faults: custom "NodeENV" variable, "prod" vs "production", and `process.env.NodeENV` passed as string, instead of variable. Also, using `.js` executable files (via `require()`) to pass configs and variables, is prone to serious issues - for instance, if you have a typo in your "config" file, the whole app will crash. Configs/variables should always be static. Better use `config` package than doing it this way.